# jquery .load() function doesn't return the latest post

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

```
$("#comment-post-button").click(function(){ 
    var event_id = document.getElementById('event-id').value;
    var url= '/post-comments/'+event_id +'/';
    $.post(url , {csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
      content:document.getElementsByName('comment-post-content')[0].value
    }); 
    $("#refresh-comments").load("/comments/" + event_id + '/', null); 
    $("#comment-post-content").val("");  
    return false;
  });
```

The above code works fine. But, the handler for '/comments/' url does not return the latest post. Here is the view:

```
def comments(request, event_id):
  if request.method == 'GET':
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id= event_id)
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
      'event' : event
    })
    return render_to_response('comments.html', variables)
```

I'm loading the object to be displayed after a successful post but, its not getting the latest addition.
Here is 'comments.html':

```
{% for comment in event.comment_set.all %}
    <a href="/{{ name }}/" class="first_name">{{ comment.author.first_name }}</a>
    {{ comment.content }}<br>
    {{ comment.pub_date }}
{% endfor %}
```

Pls help. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with asynchronous callbacks. In other words, the `load()` does not wait for `post()` to finish. So, move the code corresponding to `load` into the callback. Also, note that the reset of `comment-post-content` is also a callback from the `load` method

```
var data = {csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
  content:document.getElementsByName('comment-post-content')[0].value
}
$.post(url , data, function(){
    $("#refresh-comments").load("/comments/" + event_id + '/', function(){
        $("#comment-post-content").val(""); 
    });
});
```

Also, Please use jQuery consistently. It becomes much readable that way.